# Got an error when creating new script in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I got an error when I try to create a new script in Jupyter Notebook.
It only shows an error, but not other specific description.
Also, for the scripts I created before, I can not run any cells.

Can any body know how to solve this issues? Thanks a lot!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBjTp.png]

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more information for anybody to help you, such as the error message, your version of Jupyter and Python, and your OS. As a first try you can try uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.